# How to send a "multipart/form-data" entity with additional params via POST in Android?

Tags: android, entity, http-post

I'm a novice in Java web-interaction, so sorry for my question if somebody finds it stupid.

So, I have a form action address beginning with "https", a file that I need to post, and some additional parameter pairs to post (such as "a=add", "step=next" etc.).

In a form with which I take the example there is a parameter enctype="multipart/form-data".

So, how can I execute this POST request?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

MultipartEntity entitiy = new MultipartEntity();

// add data
entity.addPart("key", new StringBody("content"));
// files
File f = new File(path);
entity.addPart(f.getName(), new FileBody(f));

httpPost.setEntity(entity);
 HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

You are gonna need to add HttpMime (http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.2.x/download.html) to your libraries for that to work.